Kick off a background job from a SQLAlchemy hook
I am attempting to parallelize some work that's done in one of my ORM hooks. Whenever a model is created or modified, I want to make a call to a 3rd party system to reflect that update. This call, as you would imagine, is fairly expensive and I wouldn't want it to block the caller making the model change. Further, the original caller doesn't care or need to know whether the the call to the third party was successful/failed/etc.
so we'd want something like:
class User(Base):
    ...

@event.listens_for(User, 'after_insert')
def update_third_party(mapper, connect, target):
    third_party_client.create_user(target) # async and non-blocking
    return
    

I've seen and successfully tried this out with tying directly into FastApi endpoints with BackgroundTasks... but it feels incorrect to have this update be kicked off by an api call (could be easily missed if an associated API creates a User and the developer forgets to also add a background_task there). This also feels a bit overkill to stand up a more traditional job queue infra for (e.g. celery/kafka).
Is there some fairly straightforward library that accomplishes something similar to what I'm looking for?

Seems like asyncio.run_in_executor accomplishes what I'm trying to achieve. So something like:
class User(Base):
    ...

@event.listens_for(User, 'after_insert')
def update_third_party(mapper, connect, target):
     loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
     loop.run_in_executor(None, third_party_client.create_user, target)
     return

